# PHP: How to get a range from array?

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array, for ex,

```
$numarray = array("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno");
```

How can I select values in between the starting point and ending point. If the starting point is "def" and end point is "jkl", then it should return "def", "ghi" and "jkl". The starting and ending string is dynamic so it should match and then return the range of values.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @Rizier123 I just don't know where to start. I remember that I knew how to do this in javascript. I don't know whether substr is related to this but all I know is that there was some function in javascript to do this.

Comment: What do you mean with range? Do you mean the values in a certain part of the array, or the values that are between a lower and upper bound (e.g. `array(1,3,4,8, 2)`, all values between 3 and 5)?

Comment: @DaanWilmer There is html form which has 2 input fields. The user could type any starting value in 1st field and last value in another, the script would return everything between those 2 values including starting and ending value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just take an `array_slice()` from your array.

```
<?php

    $numarray = array("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno");
    $start = "def";
    $end = "jkl";   
    $startPosition = array_search($start, $numarray);
    $endPosition = array_search($end, $numarray) - $startPosition + 1;

    print_r(array_slice($numarray, $startPosition, $endPosition));

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => def
    [1] => ghi
    [2] => jkl
)
```

Comment: `$endPosition = $startPosition - array_search($end, $numarray) + 1;` must be `$endPosition = array_search($end, $numarray) - $startPosition + 1;`; +1 anyway

Answer (score 1):

For what purpose so many function call. Make not full array pass

```
$numarray = array("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno");
$start = "def";
$end = "jkl";
$out = false;

$new = array ();

foreach($numarray as $item) {
  if ($item == $start) $out = true;
  if ($out) $new[] = $item;
  if ($item == $end) break;
}

print_r($new);
```